# Good and easy to understand documentation for passbook APNS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, apns-php

Is there any good place for relatively recent documentation on how to do push notifications for iOS Passbook.

Using APNSPHP but even that's failing at the SSL connection state

Everything is either vague or outdated.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking for copy/paste code, then no.  Apple's documentation is pretty clear (and has always been).  You might want to look at Amazon AWS SNS services which now support push messaging.  APNS PHP still works very well.  The most important thing with Passbook is that you connect to the production endpoint, the development endpoint will always fail.  If you can post some more detail about what is failing with the SSL, then maybe we can help.